# Dying abroad, is anyone legally required to repatriate the body (under international law or common local laws)

Tags: international-law, repatriation

Say someone dies abroad, in most cases the family would want to bury/cremate that person in the country of origin and the cost would be covered by insurance or themselves. But assuming repatriation is not a requirement for any relatives/friends, is there any international law saying the body should be repatriated to the country of origin? Or are there many countries that have laws concerning this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No**, there's no such requirement, [the family can choose to either repatriate or bury/cremate locally](http://smartraveller.gov.au/guide/all-travellers/birth-death-marriage/death-overseas.html).  Assuming nobody claims the body, local authorities will give the local equivalent of a [pauper's funeral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauper%27s_funeral) and the remains will stay in that country.